# Find number of users count in a day who visit the url

Tags: mysql

I need a query to fetch 'number of different users count' in a day who visit the url. This is structure of my table
[image]

And i try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `userid`,`url`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,count(`userid`) as usercount FROM `mdl_log` GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

but it not work. Please help me to correct this query.

Comment: what's  the ouput?

Comment: output showing wrong count of users.

Comment: use below answer count and distinct together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use disinct and count together

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `userid`) as usercount,`url`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d') as date FROM `mdl_log` GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I think this might throw an error regarding the `url`. it's neither used by an Aggregate function nor in Group By

Comment: you should group by url as well, other wise it would return a random url from the group returned by `FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: @jonju in mysql that doesnt throw an error. but according to sql standards it should

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the total user visited to particular link on particular date, you need to Group By the url & date.

```
SELECT 
     Count(userid) as usercount ,url, FROM_UNIXTIME(time,'%Y-%m-%d') as date
FROM 
    mdl_log 
GROUP BY date,userid
```

Comment: it gives error "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: it's not work. It's return same user count who visited same url in a day. I want to different users count.

Comment: Then try Group by user